# How to enforce overriding for grand child class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, overriding, protocols

I have below hierarchical inheritance relationship in `Swift`,

```
class Base {

    func method1() { }
    func method2() { }
}

class Child: Base {

    override func method1() { }
    func method3() { }
}

class GrandChild: Child {

}
```

Now, I want to **enforce** `GrandChild` to override `method1()` from `Base` class and `method3()` from `Child` class. **How can I do so? Any workaround or better approach?**

Comment: @LalKrishna that does not answer my question. My intention is not just for making class abstract rather propagating restriction in `base->child->grandchild` flow.

Comment: This is not currently supported by Swift.

Comment: You can’t even enforce a child class to override a method since swift doesn’t have abstract classes. It’s hard to suggest a solution without knowing the use case for this but the general advice in swift for this is to use a protocol.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it on the compile time in Swift. The feature of enforcing method override is not present in Swift.

But there is a work around.

You can do that by putting a fatal error `fatalError("Must Override")`.

Consider the following example.

```
class Base {
    func method1() {
      fatalError("Must Override")
    }
    func method2() { }
}

class Child: Base {
    override func method1() { }
    func method3() {
      fatalError("Must Override")
    }
}

class GrandChild: Child {
   func method1() { }
   func method3() { }
}
```

But the above method will not give any compile time errors. For that there is another workaround.

You can create a protocol.

```
protocol ViewControllerProtocol {
   func method1()
   func method3()
}

typealias ViewController = UIViewController & ViewControllerProtocol
```

So if you implement this protocol and do not implement the methods compiler will generate an error.

As a feature of protocols in Swift you can also provide a default implementation of the methods in a protocol extension.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worth mentioning, that will be detected in runtime.

Comment: @nishith Singh The protocol approach wont make it a compulsion for the GrandChild.

Comment: Yes @RohanBhale you are correct. That is a constraint in this approach.